# How to write Element Tree dump into file

Tags: python

I am try to write the xml dump into the another file. Here is my python code

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('extract_orginal.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
with open('extract.xml', 'w') as extract:
    for item in root.findall(f"doc[@id='289e1292134534']"):
        extract.write(ET.dump(item))
```

Getting the output as "NONE" in the extract.xml file. Can you please help me.

Comment: What is in `extract.xml`?

Answer (score 0):

From the docs of `.dump()`:

"Write element tree or element structure to sys.stdout. *This function should be used for debugging only.*"

The function `.dump()` returns `None`!
I think you want to use [`.tostring()`](https://docs.python.org/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.tostring):

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('extract_orginal.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
with open('extract.xml', 'w') as extract:
    for item in root.findall(f"doc[@id='289e1292134534']"):
        extract.write(ET.tostring(item, encoding="utf-8"))
```

Comment: I tried to convert to string. But the same issue I am facing. Thanks

Comment: Updated my answer with an example, this works for me locally with a dummy file.

Comment: Hey Thank you :-). It's working